# Calling functions in Javascript namespaces

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have the following JS namespaces & functions:

**email.js**:

```
window.EMAIL = window.EMAIL || {};

EMAIL.Add = (function () {
    var add = { };

    function Test() {
        alert('EMAIL.Add.Test');
    }
}
```

**SCSD.js**:

```
window.SCSD = window.SCSD || {};

SCSD.Add = (function () {

    var add = { }

    function Test() {
        EMAIL.Add.Test();
    }
}
```

But I get this error when executing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: EMAIL.Add.Test is not a function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Assuming you've closed off those closures correctly, you haven't actually assigned `Test` to `EMAIL.Add` at any point

Comment: Downvoted because the code is syntactically incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
window.EMAIL = window.EMAIL || {};

EMAIL.Add = {};
EMAIL.Add.Test = function() { alert('EMAIL.Add.Test'); }
```

Comment: I changed email.js: window.EMAIL = window.EMAIL || {};

EMAIL.Add.Test = function () { alert('EMAIL.Add.Test');}

EMAIL.Add = (function () {....

Comment: I changed email.js:
window.EMAIL = window.EMAIL || {};

EMAIL.Add.Test = function () { alert('EMAIL.Add.Test');}

EMAIL.Add = (function () {....

I changed scsd.js:
SCSD.Add = (function () {

    var add = {};

    function Test() {
        console.log('Inside SCSD Test');
        EMAIL.Add.Test();
    }

I get the 'Inside SCSD Test', but the same error after